# How to handle drop down menu without select in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, select, automation, drop-down-menu

How to handle dropdown without select in selenium python

here is the HTML:

Completed
  
  
    
      
        
      
    
  
  
    
      
        I want to give Completed as input and click

Here is the code

```
try :

            element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/p/div/div/span[1]/input')))   
            element.click()                                                                           
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            option = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="ant-select-selection-item" and @title="Completed"]')))
            option.click()
        except:
            driver.quit()
```

Comment: A straightforward approach would involve initiating the dropdown by clicking on it, retrieving all the elements within the list, and then selecting the one that meets your specified condition. To ensure versatility and reusability, consider creating a generic function that can be applied to all same type of dropdowns in your application.

Comment: Can you correct the HTML code snippet? It starts out `class="ant-" which is not valid HTML.

Comment: <div class="ant-select-selector">
    <span class="ant-select-selection-search">
      <input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_5_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_5_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_5_list_4" readonly="" unselectable="on" value="" id="rc_select_5" style="opacity: 0;" aria-expanded="false">
    </span>
    <span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="Completed">Completed</span>